How do I load a previously named keyboard macro?
If I've previously defined a keyboard macro via C-x ( and C-x (i.e. kmacro-{start,end}-macro), named it via C-x C-k n (kmacro-name-last-macro), and then recorded a bunch of other macros in the same way, what's the quickest way to "load" the named macro back into last-kbd-macro so that it can be debugged via C-x C-k SPC (kmacro-step-edit-macro), and executed repeatedly via C-x e e e ...?
I see two options, but neither of them are good:

Retrieve the macro from the ring, e.g. via C-x C-k C-n (kmacro-cycle-ring-next) or similar.  If many macros were defined, retrieving the right one without being able to reference its name is awkward, since you have to instead cycle through the ring looking at each macro's sequence of commands in turn to figure out whether it's the one you want.

Edit the named macro via C-x C-k e M-x MACRO-NAME, select the region of the buffer which includes the macro commands, M-w to save the region to the kill ring, then edit last-kbd-macro via C-x C-k C-e, and yank the saved region to replace any existing commands, then C-c C-c (edmacro-finish-edit) to save as the new last-kbd-macro.


Surely there's a quicker way of retrieving a named macro in order to be able to debug and repeatedly execute it?

You can execute a named keyboard macro with M-x <name> (albeit that doesn't help you with the kmacro-step-edit-macro part).  It's not obvious to me that there's any link between the symbol function and the original macro, though; so I'm not sure if there's a trivial way to manipulate kmacro-ring using those symbols.  You might need to test each item with something like (equal (kmacro last-kbd-macro) (symbol-function '<name>)) (but I don't know if that's reliable).

Yeah I already knew about basic execution via M-x, and of course I could bind that to a key or write a simple wrapper for repeated execution part. But it's not convenient, and doesn't solve debugging. Thanks for the thoughts about manipulating the ring though. I noticed that counsel-kmacro exists, so maybe that's something even though it crashes for me.

FWIW, NEWS.29 for kmacro says

Kmacros are now OClosures and have a new constructor kmacro which
uses the key-parse syntax.  It replaces the old kmacro-lambda-form
(which is now declared obsolete).

The snippet below seems a reasonable starting point for Emacs versions >= Emacs 29
...
(defalias 'move3lines
  (kmacro "C-n C-n C-n"))

(defalias 'move3chars
  (kmacro "C-f C-f C-f"))

(defun set-last-kbd-macro (kmacro-sym)
 "YMMV"
  (interactive
   (list (intern
      (completing-read
       "Kmacro name: "
       (let ((result))
         (mapatoms (lambda (it)
             (when (kmacro-p (symbol-function it))
               (push it result))))
         result)))))
  (setq last-kbd-macro (kmacro--keys (symbol-function kmacro-sym))))


Do M-x set-last-kbd-macro and pick the macro name you want to load, say move3lines

Do C-x e.  Ensure that the cursor moves by 3 lines

Do M-x set-last-kbd-macro and pick the macro name you want to load, say move3chars

Do C-x e.  Ensure that the cursor moves by 3 characters




Will give it a try, thanks a lot!
